# Matplotlib not displaying image

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I am trying to use matplotlib to view an image in ipython. However, I solely obtain a description of the image as opposed to seeing the actual image:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.imshow(an_array)
Out[4]: <matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7fb626f063d0>
```

This is with the backend set to Qt5Agg or TkAgg in .matplotlibrc

I have the same issues whether or not I am working in a conda virtual environment

I am running: Scientific Linux release 6.8 (Carbon), Python 2.7.13, Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)

I have had similar issues on my local computer running MacOSX

I would be most grateful for any advice,

Thanks

Rob

Comment: Have you tried `plt.show()` ?

Comment: I just tried that - but I get no output at all from plt.show(an_array)

Comment: Do not pass the array inside it. Under `plt.imshow(an_array)` add the line `plt.show()`

Answer (score 21):

Add `%matplotlib inline` before `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` to enable automatic visualization of your plots when the cell has finished executing.

Note, however, that this works just in iPython notebooks. Normally, you'd need to call `plt.show()` (without any arguments) to visualize the plots.

Comment: Many thanks - just for my information is this normal (needing to call plt.show), or is there a minor bug in my setup?

Comment: It's absolutely normal. The idea behind this is that you can call several times `plt.plot()` (or other `matplotlib` functions) to add more plots to the same figure and then display it only when the whole figure is ready.